# How do I summon the Golem?

Tags: terraria

Do I have to have defeated Plantera in that world? Because when I try and use the Lihzahrd Altar that's supposed to summon the Golem, it doesn’t work and I can’t activate the Golem!

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per Wrigglenite' comment.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [official Terraria wiki](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Golem):

> Golem is a Hardmode, post-Plantera boss found in the Jungle Temple. **It can only be fought after Plantera has been defeated in the current world.**

So, yes, you need to defeat Plantera first.

You'll also need a [Lihzard Power Cell](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Lihzahrd_Power_Cell), if you don't have one already:

> Golem is summoned by using the ⚷ Open / Activate key on the Lihzahrd Altar, located in the final Jungle Temple chamber, **while at least one Lihzahrd Power Cell is in the player's inventory.**

Just remember that the Power Cell must be in your inventory while you use the Altar.

Comment: It can also be in your hotbar.

Comment: @SkyPaul The hotbar is part of your inventory.